# Convert point cloud to image

Tags: image, visual-studio, visual-c++, image-processing, point-cloud-library

I have a set of points generating a 3D PointCloud using PCL library.

Those 3D points have been projected into a plane and converted to 2D. What I need is to generate an image from this 2D points.

How could I do that?

Thank you. Alex.

Comment: can you elaborate your question more ? like what type of points do you have (XYZI, XYZRGB...). also if you did project them on a plane and converted them to 2D, can't see where's your problem ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/60771093/7413964

Answer (score 0):

You can use the rangeImage class to get a image of the point cloud. A tutorial can be found [here](http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/range_image_creation.php)

```
pcl::RangeImage rangeImage;
rangeImage.createFromPointCloud(pointCloud, angularResolution, 
maxAngleWidth, maxAngleHeight, sensorPose, coordinate_frame, 
noiseLevel, minRange, borderSize);
```

There is no functionality to save the image.

But you try the vtk solution of the second post [here](http://www.pcl-users.org/Writing-a-pcl-RangeImage-to-an-image)

Comment: This answer is suffering from link rot, unfortunately.