# Converting 320x240x3 point cloud matrix to 320x240x1 depth map

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, point-clouds

can anybody help me with the following problem using Python?

I have point cloud matrix got from a virtual camera, its dimension is 320x240x3, which indicates x,y,z coordinates of each point (points in camera view).

All values range from negative to positive. How can I convert this point cloud matrix to a 320x240x1 depth map which stores the positive depth value of each pixel? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, if you knew how to **convert depth image to point map** (that is your point cloud matrix), I guess you'll know the other way round.

Given the associated [camera intrinsics](http://ksimek.github.io/2013/08/13/intrinsic/), using [pinhole camera model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pinhole_camera_model), we can recover the point map using the following python code:

```py
import numpy as np  
from imageio import imread, imwrite


# read depth image in
img = imread('depth.png')  
img = np.asarray(img)

# camera intrinsics, for demonstration purposes only. change to your own.
fx, fy = 570.0, 570.0
cx, cy = 320, 240 

# suppose your depth image is scaled by a factor of 1000
z = img.astype(float) / 1000.0  

# convert depth image of shape to point map 
# here we assume depth image is of shape (480, 640)
px, py = np.meshgrid(np.arange(640), np.arange(480))  # pixel_x, pixel_y
px, py = px.astype(float), py.astype(float)
x = ((px - cx) / fx) * z 
y = ((py - cy) / fy) * z 
pmap = np.concatenate([i[..., np.newaxis] for i in (x, y, z)], axis=-1)
```

---

Now back to your question.

***Assuming your point map is in camera coordinate system*** (you haven't translated or rotated `pmap`), to convert point map to depth image we shall do:

```py
# convert point map to depth image
# that is, we are only using the points' z coordinates values
depth = (pmap[:, :, 2] * 1000).astype(np.uint16)
# now we can save the depth image to disk
imwrite('output.png', depth)
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I tried with depth = (pmap[:, :, 2] * 1000).astype(np.uint16), and it works.