# Pointcloud to image in open3d

Tags: python, python-3.x, point-clouds, open3d

I want to create image out of point cloud (.ply), using open3d. I have no problem with reading and visualizing it but can't find anything on saving it as png or jpg. My code, visualizing cloud:

```
cloud = open3d.read_point_cloud(path)
open3d.draw_geometries([cloud])
```

Comment: Take a look at [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60771093/converting-320x240x3-point-cloud-matrix-to-320x240x1-depth-map).

Comment: Please accept my answer if it worked for you.

Answer (score 12):

Try this

```
    vis = o3d.visualization.Visualizer()
    vis.create_window(visible=False) #works for me with False, on some systems needs to be true
    vis.add_geometry(your_mesh)
    vis.update_geometry(your_mesh)
    vis.poll_events()
    vis.update_renderer()
    vis.capture_screen_image(your_png_path)
    vis.destroy_window()
```

Comment: I had to make visible=True in order for the image to turn out.